# Reallocate object used by several threads

Tags: java, multithreading, arrays

I am using an array of Locks to protect concurrent accesses to the same entry of a database. Each entry of the array represents an entry of the database, but the database may grow as the program is executed, so I was planning on using `java.utils.Arrays.copyOf` to dynamically make it grow, like in:

```
lockArray = Arrays.copyOf(lockArray, lockArray.length + 1);
```

My question is if that may cause a problem with the concurrent execution; for example, if a thread is trying to read from lockArray when the copy is being done. A problem I can think of is if the copyOf operation is not atomic (which I do not know), then the array might be changed at the same that it is being copied, generating inconsistencies.

If so, is there a way of avoiding that issue?

(It's worth noting that the array will always grow, never decrease, and that the index of a database entry in the lockArray will always be the same regardless of how many times the array has grown).

Comment: Don’t think about the `lockArray` in the first place. How do you ensure that expanding the database itself works if attempted by multiple threads at the same time? If you have a lock guarding the growth of the database, simply put the expansion of the `lockArray` under the same lock.

Comment: @Holger The database is expanded externally, not by the own code. The code is only allowed to read or update entries, not to create them.

Comment: that doesn’t change anything. You still somehow decide that you need a larger `lockarray`, maybe because you detect that the database has changed externally, or whatever triggers your decision. At that time you must ensure that not multiple threads try to do the same thing at the same time. How do yo do this?

Comment: A thread is assigned to check an entry of the database, so it tries to lock it. If it turns out that there is no lock for that entry it is because the entry was created in the database after the lockarray was created in the code, so it looks if the entry exists in the database directly, and if it does that thread will make the array grow. No other thread will be trying to access that new entry (due to requirements of the software).

Comment: Another possibility (I'll implement it for safety): make grow() a synchronized method, where the first thing to be done is to check if the lock for the entry exists. If by the time you called grow() the lock didn't exist but now it does, nothing should be done.

Comment: That doesn’t help as long as threads may access your `lockArray` without invoking the `synchronized` grow() method. Declaring `lockArray` as `volatile` as said in jtahlborn’s answer would help, but to me the entire thing looks suspicious. How do you know which array entry is responsible for which database item if the database is not under your control?

Comment: By using a second array as index, which would be expanded as well in the grow() method. The database is under my control, I just don't create entries from the code (nor delete them from anywhere).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you publish the new array in a thread-safe manner (e.g. using a volatile reference) and you correctly protect the array expansion so that multiple threads cannot attempt to expand the array at the same time (e.g. using a synchronized block), then there shouldn't be a problem.  (note, you can't make the new lockArray available to other threads until you've initialized all the new lock instances).

Comment: You also need to make sure that nobody is locking something in the old lockArray that is protected by something being locked in the new lockArray.

Comment: @selig - that isn't an issue, since the locks from the old array are copied into the new array.

Comment: Thank you, @jtahlborn. I was planning on making the grow method synchronized, but I do not know what you mean by "publishing the new array in a thread-safe manner". The array is contained in an object passed to all the threads created, and each thread will only access its own entry of the array (whose index will always be the same). No method will try to access an entry still in null, do I still need to worry about "publishing it"? How?

Comment: @user2891462: As already said in the answer, making `lockArray` `volatile` implies thread-safe publishing.

Comment: I just realized that it is an array of objects, and since objects are referenced in Java, even if an entry is changed as the array is being moved, that change will be reflected in the final array. Thank you everyone.